# On start new react project I have this problem

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, react-native, vue.js

When I run `npm start`, I get this error. What is the solution for this?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: What's in the debug log file?

Comment: honestly I do not know))

Comment: You can't open it and look?

Comment: yep, it need to open a new page on localhost and to see it

Comment: Check your npm install for errors. It seems the script is failing when opening the powershell. CHeck if you have powershell installed. Also, check the NodeJS necessary steps to install the required binaries for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been addressed [here](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade/issues/150), you can refer to it.

Complete solution is

- First add Poweshell to PATH as `%SystemRoot%/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0`.
- open powershell as admin and write this command `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force`.
- last thing fire `npm-windows-upgrade`.

Answer (score -1):

Check your node version. update node & npm
try sudo npm start if you are in macOS or linux
try to download create-react-app again npm i -g create-react-app
try to create the app in another folder create-react-app APPNAME
Still not working? Then delete node module folder and run npm install
Not yet? delete both node module & package-lock.json and npm install
Try to run on another PORT

Comment: did not help ((